# LTspice Transient Analysis Simulation error

Tags: ltspice, boost

I am simulating a boost converter, however LTspice is telling me the transient analysis is only 13.8 % done, as seen below. Why is this?

[image: Simulation an]

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? You asked for 5 ms, and only got ~0.7 ms. 13.8% of 5 ms is 0.69 ms.

Comment: @ThePhoton the simulation is not running all the way to its steady-state.

Comment: What's inside the pwm and gate driver blocks?

Comment: Try setting `Rser=10m` to the output capacitor, and also to the `V_driver_supply`. Try adding a small `1...10p` cap from node `c` to ground. The custom models might also be to blame, as @ThePhoton mentions.